# special character % is transmitted to &#37; at server side through jquery AJAX call: Updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, ajaxform

I have a HTML form as the output of a java that gets a text from database and fill an input of that form with it. In form I can edit the text that on submit
Is sent back to java via a jquery AJAX call. Through java the text is saved in the database.

If I enter `test%` in text area  it is coming as `test&#37;` at server side.

Let’s say the `HTML` form looks like this :

```
<form id="form_used_0" action="#" method="post" onclick="hideAjaxList();">
    <textarea name="summary" id=" summary " data-mini="true"><%=HtmlWriter.preformat(summary)%></textarea>
    <a id="saveBtn" class="actionBtn" href="#" data-theme="b" onclick="onSave (this);">Save</a>
</form>
```

On saveBtn click this AJAX call is made:

```
function onSave(thisHref)
{
    var respData = "";
    var id = $("#id").attr("value");
    var params = $("#form_used").serialize()+"&ajaxAction=SaveHeader"+"&id="+id;
    $.post(ajaxURL, params, function(data){
        if(data.length >0) 
        {
            respData = data.substring(data.indexOf("|")+1, data.lastIndexOf("|"));
        }
    }).complete(function(){ 
        if (respData.length > 0)
        {
            var responseData = respData.split("|");
            var status = responseData[0];
            var msg = responseData[1];
            if (status == 'SUCCESS')
            {
                showSuccessMsgHeader(msg);
            }
            else if (status == 'ERROR')
            {
                showErrorMsgsOnly(msg);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I tried using the `serializeArray` method but now getting `400 Bad request error`. I checked the `form data` in network tab and found that it is showing as `unable to decode value`  beside input field .

```
function onSave(thisHref)
{
var respData = "";
var id = $("#id").attr("value");
var x = $("#form_used_0").serializeArray();
    var paramsArr = "";
    $.each(x, function(i, field){
              if(i == x.length - 1){
              paramsArr = paramsArr + field.name + "=" + field.value;
      } else {
              paramsArr = paramsArr + field.name + "=" + field.value + "&";
      }
    });
var params paramsArr +"&ajaxAction=SaveHeader"+"&id="+id;
$.post(ajaxURL, params, function(data){
if(data.length >0) 
{
respData = data.substring(data.indexOf("|")+1, data.lastIndexOf("|"));
}
}).complete(function(){ 
if (respData.length > 0)
{
var responseData = respData.split("|");
var status = responseData[0];
var msg = responseData[1];
if (status == 'SUCCESS')
{
showSuccessMsgHeader(msg);
}
else if (status == 'ERROR')
{
showErrorMsgsOnly(msg);
}
}
});
}
```

Would it be possible for anyone to help me on the same.

Comment: *The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation.* See More: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ This is expected when using `%`. You just need to convert it back from HTML Entity to ASCII Character.

Comment: thanks @Twisty . Could you please tell me where exactly I need to do that, and How can I do that.

Comment: This would be done on the Server.

Answer (score 0):

As per jQuery documentation, The *.serialize()* method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation.
You can use Apache Commons *StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml()* to decode the string at server level.
Alternatively, if required you can pass the text from textarea as an additional param, which you can use it.

Thanks.